# IntelliJ doesn't support the Bootstrap CSS classes autocomplete

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea

I work with a Java/HTML/JavaScript/Bootstrap project. When I work in the front-end, `IntelliJ` doesn't autocomplete the `CSS` classes for the Bootstrap.

What I see over the online that the people have issues when they tried to reach the `Boostrap` over the online. In my case, I have it downloaded locally in the project.

[image]

Btw, I use `Ultimate` edition if someone is wondering. What do I need to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the path to bootstrap.min.css is not resolved as it's highlighted in yellow.

Check that the path is indicated correctly. As far as I see, your 'css' folder is in 'static' folder etc.